# Is it possible to use `xxx` to define stem formulas in AsciiDoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I would like to redefine the backticks so that I can use them to type formulas in AsciiDoctor documents. For example, instead of typing

```
stem:[my formula]
```

I would like to type just

```
`my formula`
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. You have to tell ascidoc(tor) what you want. So you need the usual steps:

1. activate stem support with :stem:
2. write your equation either inline or as a block

See more details and examples here: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#activating-stem-support